Postgres(t) compression of huge json data for clients fetch call
I am using a Postgres DB to store large JSON data (~2 MB). To view and analyze the data (logfiles from different applications), I have implemented a web server with an Ag-Grid table. Based on Postgrest, I implemented a REST API to retrieve the data on the client (browser) side. All in all, the whole thing runs quite smoothly. However, depending on the network speed, it may take some time (several seconds) for the JSON to be transferred from the DB to the user's browser.
Therefore, I am looking for a way to compress the JSON before sending it to the user's browser.
I have seen that there is a Postgres gzip extension to compress data on the DB: https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-gzip
However, this extension seems to be quite old (~5 years). Does anyone know a better idea how I can compress JSON data before sending it to the user's browser via REST call?
Many thanks in advance!

Your web-server component will normally do this for you if the client supports HTTP compression

Some things are old because they just work and don't need tinkering.  Are you looking for a different compression format, or just a different way to implement the same format?  Does it need a counterpart on the client end?

Are you using nginx with postgrest already? If so, it's trivial to turn on compression in there.
